# merge values from one dataframe onto another without creating duplicates in R

Tags: r

I have data in two dataframes as follows for which I try to merge the variable "Eq..16" onto df1 using the following code `df3 = left_join(df1, df2, by = "block")` The problem is this creates many duplicate rows in my new dataset which I can get rid of using `unique()`. However, the file is large and this takes a long time. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

df1

| block | time | xp | yp | ps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2150472 | 1021. | 565. | 3485 |
| 1 | 2150473 | 1021. | 565. | 3481 |
| 1 | 2150474 | 1021. | 565. | 3477 |

df2

| original | Eq...16 | block |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fase1_01e1 | 1 | 1 |
| fase1_01e1 | 1 | 1 |
| fase1_01e1 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Your problem is that the variable "block" does not uniquely identify a row in x (and y)... If you provide a viable MRE we could find a solution. IF `df1` is a MRE, then the solution is simple: apply `unique` on "df2" before joining it to "df2"

Comment: May be doing this first and then merge `df2 <- df2[!duplicated(df2$block),]`

Comment: I agree with @PKumar, if you can remove duplicates from your df2 prior to joining.  In your reprex you have 3 duplicate records in your df2. Depending on how you're getting your data, for example, if you're getting from a query, you could update your SQL code to remove the duplicates which may be more efficient and quicker.

Comment: The solution posted by @dario worked. I am not sure how to mark a comment as the solution. So should I just delete the question or what is the correct procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If df2 has duplicates we can use `unique` the get rid of them. I.e.

```
df2_clean <- unique(df2)

library(dplyr)
df1_and_df2 <- df1 %>% left_join(df2_clean)
```

Explanation for what caused the original problem:

If we join two data.sets `x` and `y` where the common column is not unique in both of them, the join will combine **each** observation in `x` with **each** observation in `y` leading to many duplicated rows